# Why does Javascript's Date() function break for my birthday in Safari?

Tags: javascript, safari

Javascript running in Safari has a problem with my birthday. This sometimes breaks validation in forms for me (as forms check the input with the javascript output, and the days don't match anymore). I'd love to know why this happens.

My birthday is 6th Oct 1985. In Javascript, I create this using:

```
new Date(1985, 09, 06)
```

(Note that months are zero-indexed, but days and years are not.)

```js
// My birthday
console.log("1985, 09, 06: " + new Date(1985, 09, 06))

// One day earlier/later
console.log("1985, 09, 07: " + new Date(1985, 09, 07))
console.log("1985, 09, 05: " + new Date(1985, 09, 05))

// One month earlier/later
console.log("1985, 10, 06: " + new Date(1985, 10, 06))
console.log("1985, 08, 06: " + new Date(1985, 08, 06))

// One year earlier/later
console.log("1986, 09, 06: " + new Date(1986, 09, 06))
console.log("1984, 09, 06: " + new Date(1984, 09, 06))
```

Results running this in Safari are:

```
// My birthday (note the day is wrong, and the time is 11pm)
Sat Oct 05 1985 23:00:00 GMT+1000 (AEST)

// One day earlier/later
Mon Oct 07 1985 00:00:00 GMT+1100 (AEDT)
Sat Oct 05 1985 00:00:00 GMT+1000 (AEST)

// One month earlier/later
Wed Nov 06 1985 00:00:00 GMT+1100 (AEDT)
Fri Sep 06 1985 00:00:00 GMT+1000 (AEST)

// One year earlier/later
Mon Oct 06 1986 00:00:00 GMT+1100 (AEDT)
Sat Oct 06 1984 00:00:00 GMT+1000 (AEST)
```

https://jsfiddle.net/27bupLr9/

In Chrome, my birthday is created correctly:

```
console.log(new Date(1985, 09, 06))
Sun Oct 06 1985 00:00:00 GMT+1000 (AEST)
```

Comment: Which Safari version? I get `[Log] 1985, 09, 06: Sun Oct 06 1985 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (PDT)`

Comment: Version 8.0.7 (10600.7.12). Also, might it make a difference that I'm in Australia?

Comment: Mmh, I guess the clue may be in the daylight saving time change. The first date would be Oct 06, 1985 00:00:00 in AEDT, so the date looks correct (techincally?). However, in 1985 DTS change for AEST was on Oct 27...

Comment: It's definitely daylight savings related. The different browsers must be using different timezone information. Try running:

`new Date(Date.UTC(1985, 09, 06, 0, 0, 0))`

Chrome gives: `Sun Oct 06 1985 10:00:00 GMT+1000 (AEST)` whereas safari gives `Sun Oct 06 1985 11:00:00 GMT+1100 (AEDT)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been resolved in macOS High Sierra.